# Prove that $\{u_1, u_2, u_3\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose

$$u_1=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix},
\qquad
u_2=\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\ 0 \\ 3
\end{pmatrix},
\qquad
u_3=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 5 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
 Prove that $\{u_1, u_2, u_3\}$ is a
basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Also, suppose $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear transformation such that:
$$
T(u_1)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix},
\qquad
T(u_2)=\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix},
\qquad
T(u_3)=\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Find $T((x, y, z)^T)$ for all $(x,y,z)^T\in\mathbb{R}^3$

I tried to prove linear independence by setting up the matrix and trying to row reduce but can't seem to get everything equal to $0$.

Comment: Does it help to observe that $u_3-5u_1 = [1 \, 0 \, 0]^T$, and then $(u_2-2u_3+10u_1)/3 = [0 \, 0 \, 1]^T$?

Answer (score 1):

To show that $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^3$ it suffices to show that the matrix
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 & u_2 & u_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 5 \\
0 & 3 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
has rank three. To do so, we have several options.

**Option 1.** Recall that a square matrix has full rank if and only if it has nonzero determinant. In our case, $\det(A)=3$. Hence $A$ has rank three.

**Option 2.** Row reduce and count the pivots in $\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref(A)$. In our case, $\rref(A)$ can be computed with the row reductions

- swap rows 1 and 2
- scale row 2 by $1/2$
- add $-3$ times row 2 to row 3
- scale row 3 by $-2/3$
- add $-5$ times row 3 to row 1
- add $-1/2$ times row 3 to row 2

Performing these row-reductions gives
$$
\rref(A)=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Hence $A$ has rank three.

To find a formula for $T$, note that
$$
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}\right]
=
\lambda_1
\left[\begin{array}{r}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array}\right]
+\lambda_2
\left[\begin{array}{r}
2 \\
0 \\
3
\end{array}\right]
+\lambda_3
\left[\begin{array}{r}
1 \\
5 \\
0
\end{array}\right]
$$
if and only if 
$$
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}\right]
=
A
\left[\begin{array}{r}
\lambda_1\\ \lambda_2\\ \lambda_3
\end{array}\right]\tag{1}
$$
But (1) holds if and only if
$$
\left[\begin{array}{r}
\lambda_1\\ \lambda_2\\ \lambda_3
\end{array}\right]=
A^{-1}
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
-5 & 1 & \frac{10}{3} \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\
1 & 0 & -\frac{2}{3}
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{r}
-5 \, x + y + \frac{10}{3} \, z \\
\frac{1}{3} \, z \\
x - \frac{2}{3} \, z
\end{array}\right]
$$
Hence
\begin{align*}
T\left[\begin{array}{r}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}\right]
&= T(\lambda_1 u_1+\lambda_2 u_2+\lambda_3 u_3) \\
&= \lambda_1 T(u_1)+\lambda_2 T(u_2)+\lambda_3 T(u_3) \\
&= \left(-5 \, x + y + \frac{10}{3} \, z\right) T(u_1)
+\left(\frac{1}{3} \, z\right) T(u_2)
+\left(x - \frac{2}{3} \, z\right) T(u_3) \\
&=\left(-5 \, x + y + \frac{10}{3} \, z\right) \left[\begin{array}{r}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right]
+\left(\frac{1}{3} \, z\right) 
\left[\begin{array}{r}
2 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right]
+\left(x - \frac{2}{3} \, z\right) \left[\begin{array}{r}
1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array}\right] \\
&=
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x \\
x - \frac{2}{3} \, z \\
-5 \, x + y + \frac{10}{3} \, z
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see your work for the row reducing. However, once you establish that $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ then given any $(x,y,z)$ we have;

$$(x,y,z) = a_1 u_1+ a_2 u_2 + a_3 u_3$$

Using linearity of $T$ you have;

$$T((x,y,z)^T) = a_1 T(u_1) + a_2 T(u_2) + a_3 T(u_3) = a_1 \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0\\1 \end{bmatrix}+ a_2 \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0\\0 \end{bmatrix}+ a_3 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that the matrix $U$ whose columns are the vectors $u_i$ given is such that the determinant is not zero, in which case they can form a basis.

Indeed, the determinant is not zero and hence $U$ is invertible.

You then have $$TU=\left(\begin{matrix}0&2&1\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{matrix}\right)$$

So you will be able to calculate $$T=\left(\begin{matrix}0&2&1\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{matrix}\right)U^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since there are three vectors, it’s enough to show that they’re linearly independent to prove that they’re a basis for $\mathbb R^3$. For this particular set of vectors, you can do this by inspection. If you have $au_1+bu_2+cu_3=0$, then $b$ must be zero because $u_2$ is the only vector with a non-zero third coordinate. Once you’ve eliminated that, the same reasoning shows that $c$ must also be zero, leaving $au_1=0$, which means that $a=0$, too.

The other answers you’ve gotten give you different ways to solve the second half of the problem.